# twitter wrong calculation of character limit

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, social-networking

Please find jsfiddle link "http://jsfiddle.net/HDT8J/2/"

```
<div id="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=/" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="I am a tweet. I have exactly 140 characters. If you want to make sure that I only have 140 characters you can check for http://bit.ly/N7vu5k" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div>
```

when I try to post tweet with tweetWithUrl string its showing -2 as character limit and I cant able to post tweet

while when I did same thing with tweetWithText string  it takes proper 140 character limit

I figured out that even though "http://bit.ly/N7vu5k" this URL length is 20 still tweeter calculating extra 2 characters.

Comment: Take a look here: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/7891

Comment: so in this case 23 character are reserved for link, and actual message (data-text) length should be maximum 117 am I right? so am I need to shorten data-text?